# Understanding a certain step in a proof about a basis of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-explanation

This is a theorem from Roman's textbook "Advanced Linear Algebra"(p.$48$).

> **Theorem** $1.9.$ Let $V$ be a nonzero vector space. Let $I$ be a linearly independent subset of $V$ and let $S$ be a spanning set of $V$ containing $I$. Then there is a basis $B$ such that $I \subseteq B \subseteq S$.

**Proof:**

> Let $A = \{$all linear independent subsets of $S$ containing $I \}, A \neq \varnothing$ since $I \in A$
>   Now, let $C = \{I_k | k \in K \}$ be any chain in a poset $A$.
>
> $\bigcup\limits_{k \in K} I_k \in A$ since it is linearly independent and is contained in $S$. So $\bigcup\limits_{k \in K} I_k$ is an upper bound for $C$, that is, any chain in $A$ has an upper bound, so Zorn's lemma tells us that $A$ contains a maximal element $B$.
>
> Now we need to prove that that $B$ is a basis for $V = span(S)$.
>
> If any $s \in S$ is not a linear combination of the elements of $B$, then $\{s \} \cup B \subseteq S$ is also linearly independent contradicting the maximality of $B$. So, $S \subseteq span(B)$ **and so $V = span(S) \subseteq span(B)$**.

What is don't understand is why "and so"?
I got that $S \subseteq span(B)$. How does is tell us that $V = span(S) \subseteq span(B)$?

Comment: we have v=span (s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A \subseteq B$, then $span(A) \subseteq span(B)$. In this case we have $span(S) \subseteq span(span(B))$, but $span(span(B)) = span(B)$.

Comment: But why $span(span(B)) = span(B)$? Obviously, $span(span(B)) = V$, but how can we know that so is $span(B)$?

Comment: Because the span of a set is the set of all linear combinations of the vectors in that set. When you take the span of a set that already contains all linear combinations, you get nothing new, so you just get the same set back.

Comment: Yeah. thank you. Got that.

Answer (score 0):

$S$ is a set of vectors in the vector space $span(B)$ so it spans a vector space that is a subspace of $span(B)$, eventually coincident with $span(B)$.